# Sound inconsistency in Finding Nemo

Tags: plot-explanation, finding-nemo

When Nemo does his 2nd attempt at blocking the fish tank cleaning fan, there is a sound inconsistency.

You would need to know that he can only get out by jamming the fan with a pebble, after which it finally comes to a stop so he can swim through the tube.

So why does the fan make the jamming sound when Gill and Folk shove the stem of the plant into the tube when it's already stationary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its an inconsistency. The first time when Nemo puts the pebble into the fan, he swims back into the tank. During this time, the other fishes are busy uprooting the fake plant and pushing it into the fan. They don't notice Nemo has already arrived. When they push the plant into the fan, the fan is pushed across, and what we hear is the sound of the stone being scraped. The fan is jammed because of the stone, so if anyone tries to push it, the stone will still block the fan which produces the noise that you just heard.